# Check if mathversion (font) is defined

Tags: fonts, math-mode, conditionals

One can define a new mathversion using `\DeclareMathVersion{sans}`.

I wonder if I can test the existence of such a font definition, for example with

```
\IfMathVersionDefined{sansmath}
  {math font is defined}
  {math font is not defined}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you just looking for this?

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IfMathVersionDefined}[3]{%
  \expandafter\@ifundefined\csname mv@#1\endcsname{#3}{#2}%
}
\makeatother
```

The above is motivated by the fact that `\DeclareMathVersion{#1}` defines `\mv@#1`.

Comment: Exactly. I failed to find the code where this is defined.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathVersion{blub}


\begin{document}
\ifcsname mv@blub\endcsname
 math version blub exist
\else
 math version blub  doesnt exist
\fi 

\ifcsname mv@bla\endcsname
 math version bla exist
\else
 math version bla doesnt exist
\fi 

\end{document}
```